# Codeigniter ajax request not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I send one request to controller ,And When I alert(tele) to controller it is display values,But in controller it shows empty,,

But Other date1 and date2 are working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#buttonsearch').click(function(){
var date1=$("#date1").val(); 
var date2=$("#date2").val();vartele=$("#tele").val();
 alert(tele);
 $.ajax(
 {
 type: "POST",
 url: '<?php echo site_url('totalorders/orderajax'); ?>',
 data: 'date1=' + date1 + '&date2='+ date2 +'& tele ='+ tele,
 success: function(data)
 {
 alert(data);
 $("#customers2").html(data);
 }}); });});
</script>
```

controller code..

```
 public function orderajax()
    {

         $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $date1=$this->input->post('date1');
        $date2=$this->input->post('date2');
        $tele=$this->input->post('tele');
        $data['tele']=$tele;
        if(($date1 != '') && ($date2 != '') && ($tele == ''))
        {

            $data['orders'] = $this->orderdetails->get_ajaxsearchorders($date1,$date2,$tele);
        }
        else 
        {
            $sss=$tele;
            $data['orders'] = $this->orderdetails->get_ajaxsearchorders1($sss);
        }
        $this->load->view('orderviewajax',$data);
    }
```

can you guys help me where i was wrong..

Note : only 'tele' value is not working date1,date2 are working..

Comment: remove extra space after & 
+'& tele ='+ tele"

Comment: yes it is working,,.Thanks..

Comment: use this data: {date1: date1, date2: date2, tele: tele},

Comment: Please do not tag-spam... your question can't be about CodeIgniter version 2 and 3 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Give the space between the key word **var** and the variable name tele. Check the following line.

```
var tele = $("#tele").val();
```

Comment: This can't be the problem because the OP says that `alert(tele)` is working.

Answer (score 0):

add space in variable declaration. and while posting data dont give a space.
For Eg:

```
             type:"POST",
             url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/date_report",
             data:'year='+nep_year+'&month='+nep_month,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root problem is the space you've embedded within the query string in this part:

```
... +'& tele ='+ tele
```

Remove the space between `&` and `tele`...

```
... +'&tele ='+ tele
```

HOWEVER, you don't need to collect each value and manually construct a query string.

Simply use jQuery `.serialize()`, which collects the form's values and constructs the query string automatically.

```
data:  $('form').serialize(),
```